# Dynamic combo and mootools get method doesn't work in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, combobox, get, mootools, set

I have a problem with the Mootools `get` method and IE8. This is the thing.

I have a select combo that loads dynamically the options with a Request.HTML

HTML:

```
<select name="model" id="model" class="customSelectModel">
    <option>Modelo</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var req = new Request.HTML({
        method: 'get',
        url: loadModels,
        data: "model="+model,
        update: $('model'),
}).send();
```

Also, the select has a custom style, with this: http://vault.hanover.edu/~stilson/simpleselectstyle/

The problem is when I load the content of `model`, IE throw me an error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

I don't know why, but

```
span.addEvent('change',function(){
     span.set('text',this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].get('text'));
});
```

does not work with IE8 (as usually, it works perfectly with the other browsers) . I'm using Mootools 1.3.2

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot update `<select>` elements content via `innerHTML` in a cross-browser fashion, which the `update: $("model")` will *try* to do.

I would suggest refactoring via an `onComplete: function() {}` where you:

- delete all child elements of `model`
- iterate through options elements sent via HTML and inject them into the `model`
- call whatever method your custom styling provides (if it has any) to freshen object members for `model` and `fireEvent("change")` to highlight your new selected choice for scripting, if you need it.

for your second question.

`this.options.get("value")` returns selected value.

if its a multiple select, it can have more than 1 value.

mootools provides `selectel.getSelected()` which returns an array of options you can iterate to get text from. hence:

`selectel.getSelected().get("text")` will return `["sometext"]` or `["sometext1", "sometext2"]` on a multiple select.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitar. As you explain, after deleting all child of select with .empty(), I've tried to iterate with this `responseElements.each(function(e) {        e.inject($('model'));       });` but it doesn't work in IE. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: thanks, mate. I can't believe how INTERNET EXPLORER still making its own annoying rules and how we need to find workarounds for that shit... Therefore the solution is, prior to inject it, to wrap `<options>` in a select, but I'll try JSON anyway.

Comment: oddly enough. http://jsfiddle.net/mpSsJ/4/ -> tried it in jquery and it works. so they must have a workaround for this in their code (i am no jquery user so this was an experiment). go figure - discussed with some core devs of mootools who were not impressed.

Comment: for the record – http://jsfiddle.net/eme_dlr/UfPX8/ *EVEN* IE is not able to understand this correspondence `opt.innerHTML = responseElements[i].innerHTML`, so finally I've changed my sql query and I've added an id  to select fields in order to put them into innerHTML: `opt.innerHTML = responseElements[i].id;`. 100% awesomeness.

Comment: `this.response.elements.length` comes 1 short if options dont have a parent select in ie8 - careful!